# Cannot work around ArithmeticException? / by zero?

Tags: java, arithmeticexception

I'm having trouble working around an ArithmeticException I'm getting from my `getAverageScore()` method in my `Student` class. I'm trying to write a program that reads the following text file `scores.txt`:

```
34     c081 c082 c083 c084
S2023  99   75   85   62
S2025  -1   92   67   52
S1909  100  83   45   -1
```

The c numbers such as c081 are course codes at the school, and the s numbers such as s2023 are student numbers. The figures in the middle represent their scores, the -1 also means they weren't enrolled in the unit.

I want to be able to write a program where I can give output as the student with the highest average across their classes, with that average and their student number. I want to be able to make sure the -1 values aren't included in that class average, so that if a student has one of those, their average is only calculated for the classes they did actually take.

This is the `Student` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student {

    private String studentNumber;
    private ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Student(String studentText) {
        String[] parts = studentText.split(studentText, ' ');
        this.studentNumber = parts[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
            scores.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[i + 1]));
        }
    }

    public String getStudentNumber() {
        return this.studentNumber;
    }

    public float getAverageScore() {
        int sum = 0;
        int numberOfCoursesNotTaken = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <this.scores.size(); i++) {
            if (i != -1) {
            sum += this.scores.get(i);
            System.out.println(sum);
            } else {
                numberOfCoursesNotTaken++ ;
                System.out.println(numberOfCoursesNotTaken);
            }
        }
        return sum / (this.scores.size() - numberOfCoursesNotTaken);
    }


}
```

I'm calling this method from the following class:

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MySchool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfStudents;
        ArrayList<Student> allStudents = new ArrayList<Student>() ;

        try {

            File scoresFile = new File("Scores.txt");
            Scanner scoresFileReader = new Scanner(scoresFile);


            String headerRow = scoresFileReader.nextLine();

            char c = headerRow.charAt(0);
            numberOfStudents = Character.getNumericValue(c);  


            for (int studentI = 0; studentI < numberOfStudents; studentI++) {
                String studentText = scoresFileReader.nextLine();
                System.out.println(studentText);
                Student student = new Student(studentText);
                allStudents.add(student);
            }

            scoresFileReader.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        float highestAverage = 0;
        String highestScoringStudentNumber = null;


        for (Student student : allStudents) {
            if (student.getAverageScore() > highestAverage) {
                highestAverage = student.getAverageScore();
                highestScoringStudentNumber = student.getStudentNumber();
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Highest scoring student: " + highestScoringStudentNumber);
    }
}
```

However, the return line of `getAverageScore()` in `Student` gives the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Student.getAverageScore(Student.java:34)
    at MySchool.main(MySchool.java:42)`

I thought I'd solved this issue using the `numberOfCoursesNotTaken` variable? Could anyone help me?

Comment: `if (i != -1)`, when is this going to be `false`? Why is the `else` block there if it isn't going to be? And what are the contents of the `Scores.txt`?

Comment: The contents of `scores.txt` is at the top of my query. So -1 means that the student didn't actually take the course, so I was trying to catch their marks, if they did take the course and get an average for them

Comment: Then shouldn't the condition be `if (this.scores != -1)` ? Previously, I intended to ask when is `if (i != -1)` supposed to be `true`?

Comment: @boobalan Do you mean like this?

```
public float getAverageScore() {
  int sum = 0;
  int numberOfCoursesNotTaken = 0;
  
  for (int i = 0; i <this.scores.size(); i++) {
   if (this.scores.get(i) != -1) {
   sum += this.scores.get(i);
   System.out.println(sum);
   } else {
    numberOfCoursesNotTaken++ ;
    System.out.println(numberOfCoursesNotTaken);
   }
  }
  return sum / (this.scores.size() - numberOfCoursesNotTaken);
 }

```

This still gives the same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really recommend removing invalid values as soon as they are found. You could replace your `Student` constructor by the following:

```
public Student(String studentText) {
    String[] parts = studentText.split(" "); // previously (studentText, ' ')
    this.studentNumber = parts[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
        int score = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]); // NOT i+1
        if (score >=0) this.scores.add(score);
    }
}
```

While you are at it, you can greatly simplify your average-score calculation (now that there are no -1s):

```
public float averageScore() {
   if (scores.isEmpty()) {
      return 0; // avoids divide-by-zero
   } else {
      int total = 0;
      for (int score : scores) total += score;
      return total / (float) scores.size();
   }
}
```

Comment: This was brilliant! Thank you, I'm super new to object oriented programming and am having a lot of trouble finding my feet on thinking through a problem properly, so this was great!

Comment: There is a bug in `studentText.split(studentText, ' ');`, is it not?

Comment: You're correct, I think there may actually be an issue with something in my `Student` constructor, as the code above fixed the arithmeticException itself but my output is still null

Comment: @boobalan fixed, thanks - I did not actually run the code before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Student class -> getAverageScore : in the for loop, you're checking if i != -1, instead of if scores.get(i) != -1.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried modifying the if statement to include that and still get the same divide by zero error

Comment: It is normal to always get a division by zero, but keep the statement like so, otherwise it's useless.From what we have, the (this.scores.size() - numberOfCoursesNotTaken) is equal to zero, what means this.scores.size() is equal to zero (numberOfCoursesNotTaken was null too because of the previous condition). The problem is in the student declaration : I really advise you to print StudentText in MySchool class to check, and then print the entire content of scores in the Student class.

Comment: There are many more problems in the code than just this `if` statement. The `for` loop in the constructor is also wrong. But even if that would all be technically correct, there are still some logical problems in the algorithm. I fear, OP has to rework the whole design. I fear, a one-sentence-answer is not able to catch all these problems.